# Function for adding annotation (text + line) to an svg using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
// legend description for fire colors
legendContText = wrapLabel("Color indicates time to containment (darker = longer) ranging from 8 to 114 days.  This one took 113 days.", 160);
const legendCont = legendOverlay.append("g")
  .attr("class","legend cont");
const legendContSpans = legendCont.append("text")
  .attr("y", yScale(70));
legendContText.forEach(function(string) {
  legendContSpans.append('svg:tspan')
  .text(string)
  .attr("font-size",yScale(0.28).toString()+"rem")
  .attr('x', yScale(-150))
  .attr('dy', yScale(5))
});
legendCont.append("line")
  .attr("class","legend cont")
  .attr("x1", yScale(-150))
  .attr("y1", yScale(57))
  .attr("x2", yScale(-140))
  .attr("y2", yScale(70));
```

So I created a visualization in d3 and I add several annotations to a large svg - each one consisting of several lines of text (one text object with several tspans) and one line.  Shown above is the code for one such annotation.

My code works fine (check out the result at http://heidistockton.com/fireandice/) - my issue is that it is WAY too repetitive and definitely not best practice (I have like 10-15 of them and they comprise nearly 40% of my code by row count).  Can someone help me determine a way to create a function for adding one such annotation?

I would expect the inputs of such a function to be:

1. a string
2. a width for the text wrapping
3. a class name for the annotation (for cleaner html)
4. x/y coordinates for the text box, and
5. two sets of x/y coordinates for the line

The "wrapLabel" function just takes a string and breaks it into smaller chunks based on length (code from Carys Mills).   I would expect to either nest the wrapLabel function inside an annotation function or just include the output of the wrapLabel function as an input for the annotation function.

Full code for my project can be found here: https://github.com/heidi8297/heidi8297.github.io/blob/main/fireandice/main.js

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first 3 points. Regarding the question 5: I suppose you need a function that returns coordinates of a line by a certain angle and start/end radius? Is that correct?